# Solving an eigenvalue problem on the open unit rectangle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega=(0,1)\times(0,1)$ and consider the boundary value problem
$$\begin{cases}\Delta^2u=f\\ u(x,y)=\Delta u(x,y)=0,& x,y\in\partial\Omega \end{cases}$$

I want to solve this boundary value problem and I have tried using Green's functions and Fourier transforms, but I have no luck. Can someone help me out? MAybe I am using the wrong approach.

Comment: What are the conditions on $f$? Also, what is the connection between the title and your question?

Comment: This is not an eigenvalue problem.

Comment: Would the sine transform work?

Comment: Why did using the Green's function fail? Can you be more specific? You might have to understand your problem better, too.